# Tableau - Plotting specific dates on a Gantt chart

Tags: tableau-api

I have a gantt chart that shows for each project - the start date and using the number of days a project has been worked on, a gantt chart.

I also have a "Last worked on" date for each project that I'd like to plot on the gantt bars for each project.

Any inputs on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Display it as Text on the bar.
[image]